# correcting bad records : Need help in python, code for removing line breaks in between the records

Tags: python

I am working on a set of files that has bad records in similar csv files.

Issue: The linebreaks appear in between the records and therefore the records breaks and move to the next line as a new record. some records span 3 lines if there are more line breaks (particular in the address column or field). The line breaks are also appearing for some other columns -Product name. these columns - Address and Product name are in the middle of the record.

Bad records Example:

```
FirstName|LastName|Address1|Address2|Address3|city|state|country|productname|Amount\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23324.|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer|11\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23324.\r\n
|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer|11\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23\r\n
2332\r\n
4.|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer|11\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23324.|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer\r\n
|11\r\n
```

Header and first detail record are good records
and the rest are bad records as line breaks \r\n appears in between

Total expected records should be 5 including header

```
FirstName|LastName|Address1|Address2|Address3|city|state|country|productname|Amount\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23324.|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer|11\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23324.|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer|11\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23224.|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer|11\r\n
abc|def|abcwe123|23324.|23234|somecity|somestate|US|eerwer|11\r\n
```

I am thinking of a high-level solution as below :

1. Read the header record and store the No of columns, No of required delimiters in a table
2. Read the detail record and check the delimiters, if the same skip
3. Read the detail record and check the delimiters, if not the same

   1. check the last correct delimiter position and replace the linebreak to space
4. read the next file in the same folder and do the same as above

Need some help as I am not a coder. Not able to handle this issue in ADF or Power BI

Comment: Please try coding it yourself first. SO is not a coding service, it's for solving problems with existing code.

Comment: Hey, I could able to code myself and got the desired output with the code below. Need help on how to read all the similar files in a folder and fix the issue?

Comment: Which code? Please [edit] it into your question.